# How to Set Background Image from IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, application-data

I am loading a `BitmapImage` from `IsolatedStorage` and would like to set the value to the background of MainPage. I am not sure how to properly do this?

TombstoningHelper.cs

```
public async Task StorePhoto(Stream photoStream, string fileName)
    {
        // persist data into isolated storage
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        using (Stream current = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await photoStream.CopyToAsync(current);
        }
    }

public async Task<BitmapImage> RetrievePhoto(string fileName)
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        Stream imageStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

        //Check if file exists

        // display the file as image
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.SetSource(imageStream);

        return bi;
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set Page Theming
        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
        TombstoningHelper tsh = new TombstoningHelper();

        if (Settings.TransparentBackground.Value == null)
            ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Graphics/" + Settings.Background.Value, UriKind.Relative)); //No Error
        else
            ib.ImageSource = tsh.RetrievePhoto(Constants.BackgroundImageName); //Error occurs here

        LayoutRoot.Background = ib;
```

I am getting an error above stating `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage>' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the await keyword since your Helper's methods are asynchronous.

```
else
    ib.ImageSource = await tsh.RetrievePhoto(Constants.BackgroundImageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use await statement, like this: 
ib.ImageSource = await tsh.RetrievePhoto(Constants.BackgroundImageName);